# Google visualization world map

Tags: php, json, google-maps

I'm trying to retrieve results using json in order to display world map with country list.

This is what I got so far:

```
function drawRegionsMap() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getlist.php",
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(result) {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(result);

        var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data)
        view.setColumns([0, 1])
        var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(
            document.getElementById('map'));
        chart.draw(data, options);

        var geochart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(
            document.getElementById('map'));
        var options = {
            width: "auto",
            height: "auto",
            colorAxis: {
                colors: ['#E4B6D3', '#E06D94']
            } // Map Colors 
        };

        geochart.draw(data, options);
    });

};

google.load('visualization', '1', {
    'packages': ['geochart']
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);
```

result returned from getlist.php is in json format:

```
{
   "Country":[
      "Germany",
      "United States",
      "Brazil",
      "France",
      "RU"
   ],
   "Hits":[
      200,
      300,
      400,
      500,
      600,
      700
   ]
}
```

php code:

```
  $data = array();
  $data['Country'] = array();
  $data['Hits'] = array();

  $country = array('Germany','United States','Brazil','France','RU');
  $hits = array(200,300,400,500,600,700);

  for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++){
      $data['Country'] = $country;
      $data['Hits'] = $hits;
  }

echo json_encode($data);
```

Looking in firebug console, I'm always getting : Error: Not an array
I've been trying to solve this puzzle for hours, but no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The returned result is an object, not an array.

The expected array would be:

```
[
 ["Country","Hits"],
 ["Germany",200],
 ["United States",300],
 ["Brazil",400],
 ["France",500],
 ["RU",600]
]
```

Modified PHP-code that returns this array:

```
<?php
  $data = array(['Country','Hits']);


  $country = array('Germany','United States','Brazil','France','RU');
  $hits = array(200,300,400,500,600,700);

  foreach ($country as $k => $v){
      $data[] = array($v,$hits[$k]);
  }

  echo json_encode($data);
?>
```